# AsyncTask already started onCreate

Tags: android, multithreading, background, android-asynctask

When I try to execute an AsyncTask from a button click, my app says the task is already started.  I don't execute the task anywhere in onCreate or onResume or anything like that.  Can a task be started when my activity is created without me executing it programatically?

```
    // Login button
    Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {                
            loginTask.execute("");
        }
    });


// Background login thread
private AsyncTask<Object, String, String> loginTask = new AsyncTask<Object, String, String>(){

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) 
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "Login task started");
        LoginManager lm = new LoginManager();
        String username = emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordText.getText().toString();
        loginBundle = new Bundle();
        loginBundle.putString(Constants.LOGIN_HANDLER_ID, lm.login(username, password));
        loginMessage = Message.obtain(null, 0);
        loginMessage.setData(loginBundle);
        loginHandler.sendMessage(loginMessage);
        return "";
    }

};
```

This is the only place I call execute, and it's a button that I'm creating in the onCreate() method.  When the task is executed, I get a task already started error.

I thought maybe I'm not cancelling the thread correctly, and so I rebooted my Motrola Xoom.  I ran the app once the Xoom was started, and I still got this error.  What can I do?  The app is using Android SDK 8... and I'm running on a Motorola Xoom.

Comment: You can't execute an AsyncTask once it's finished.  You have to create a new object and start it.

Comment: You seem to pass "" as task argument and also return "", even you do not really need it. Replace `String` with `Void` so you won't need to do that anymore unless really needed

Comment: That's true, I should start a new object.  But just out of curiousity, why doesn't the device kill that finished AsyncTask when I reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a call to your AsyncTask like this

```
new LoginTask().execute("");
```

where

```
private class LoginTask extends
    AsyncTask<Object,String, String> {
.....

}
```

Comment: Thanks!!!  It looks like I don't have to use cancel() anymore too.  I'm guessing that android cleans these threads up for me? I don't want someone trying to login a bunch of times spawning a bunch of threads that never die.

Comment: No, you dont need to cancel() it either. That is done by onPostExecute(). It is like a destructor and it will clean the thread and free the resources as soon as the execution is over. You dont need to worry about it.